# C# Nugget Server Error

Tags: html, version, websocket

I'm currently trying to get a simple client \ server websocket demo up and running and I'm trying to use the [C# Nugget project](http://nugget.codeplex.com/) as my server.  I can connect to the server through Netscape (v5.1.4) but not through Chrome (v18.0.1) and I've tracked the issue down to the client handshake.

Nugget expects the client handshake to be in the following format which is exactly how Netscape is sending it:

[image: expected client handshake]

Chrome's client handshake on the other hand is looking like this:

[image: chromes client handshake]

I've highlighted the differences in the two requests that are causing the problem in Nugget server - the sec-websocket parameters.

I'm guessing that Netscape and Chromes implementation of the client handshake are based on different versions of the websocket specification.  **Has anyone got any more information on this?  Is it OK to just add code to handle both types of handshake or is one deprecated?**

Any insights welcome,

James

*Resources: [Understanding Websocket Client Handshakes](http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/12/30/understanding-websocket-handshake/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Netscape is speaking the older, deprecated, [Hixie](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) variant of the protocol.  Safari also uses this.  Chrome uses the more modern [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).  You can expect all browsers to use RFC 6455 eventually.

Assuming you want to support as many client types as possible, its okay (indeed correct) to add code to handle both variants.  Note that the data framing for post-handshake reads/writes also changes depending on the protocol variant being used.